# How to debug Joomla! after render the last module?

Tags: joomla-2.5, performance, debug

I have a site with some performance issues. I have tried to debug it with no much luck.

I have the following information:

```
...
Application 0.527 seconds (+0.004); 6.93 MB (+0.018) - afterRenderModule mod_banners (Publicidad Leaderboard)
Application 10.656 seconds (+10.129); 7.01 MB (+0.083) - afterRender
```

There is a gap of 10 seconds and I have no idea where to look. Start disabling / enabling plugins and modules is like overkill the problem.

In the search for a solution I found that the gap is related to the first time the the cache is generated. This seems to be an expected behaviour, so, it's ok. However, after the system has the cache ready:

```
Application 0.470 seconds (+0.004); 6.72 MB (+0.019) - afterRenderModule mod_banners (Publicidad Leaderboard)
Application 0.984 seconds (+0.514); 6.76 MB (+0.043) - afterRender
```

Half a second may not be much, but when it comes from 'no where', at least for me it's a matter to worry.

So, I'm wondering if there is a way to extract more information between the afterRender of the last module and the final afterRender so i can figure out what part tune up.

Answer (score 1):

Performance is a big subject. However, this article, from [Roberto Segura Blog](http://phproberto.com), shows a practical case to answer your question.

**Joomla! rendering tools benchmark** 
http://phproberto.com/en/blog/21-joomla-rendering-benchmarks

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to be able to track layouts file accesses. Is that possible in Joomla! 2.5.x?

Comment: Not sure, J 2.5 is almost EOL, it has only received bug fixes http://developer.joomla.org/development-status.html